# Coreopsis seems to have suddenly died in the last month

Tags: flowers

Pictures of plant -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/URBX6.jpg

I have had a coreopsis (presto) in a sunny spot in my front garden for about a year, it was in good health up to a few weeks ago. It had seemed to survive Winter quite well, but now I’m not sure what has happened to it. It has not been particularly cold lately, it was definitely much colder during Winter.

It looks like it’s collapsed from the inside or something crushed it as there was a few partially broken branches/stems, I have removed any completely dead segments and this is the remaining plant. The leaves seem OK but none of them plant seems to be upright and supporting itself, am worried that it's slowly dying but there hasn't been much progress in it either dying or coming back to life.

I’ve been watering it regularly along with the rest of the plants around it, everything else is fine. Not sure if I should cut it back or leave it and hope for the best

Thanks for any advice,

Comment: What does "watering it regularly" mean? Coreopsis prefers dry to medium moisture environments with a well-drained soil, and fertilization is not necessary.

Comment: it was usually once a week since we've been lacking with rainfall lately, probably twice a week now since I'm at home in lockdown with nothing else to do! Maybe I should cut back on that a bit?

Comment: I don't think that's too much. The leaves seem to look fairly good - not drooping or distressed.  It looks like you're even getting some flower buds. I think it just needs some time. What part of the world are you in?

Comment: yeah there have been buds on it for a while now, no flowers yet. It just looks, flattened? I'm in Ireland, ironically we could do with some rain soon - I think I'll get what I wished for looking at the forecast for the rest of the week!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look too bad at all, it's definitely not dead - I wouldn't cut it back though, every time I've cut mine back in spring,they just up and die on me. Just give it some time.. we've got rain coming in the south and west of the UK, not sure if that includes Dublin, but  you may not need to continue giving it water as the warm dry spell is about to  break.